# Is there a way to make a conditional statement based on whether or not someone presses a button (tkinter)

Tags: python, list, tkinter

Here is my code:

```
    root = tkinter.Tk()

    canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=960, height=720)
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('TitleScreen.png'))

    canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=tkinter.NW, image=image)
    canvas.create_text(485, 375, font=("Times", 25, 'bold'),
                       text='You live in Valencia, Venezuela. You have 2 kids, and a '
                            '\n'
                            'significant other. You barely have enough money to take care '
                            '\n'
                            'of your family, food is running out, and electricity outages '
                            '\n'
                            'are a daily occurrence. Do you  want to leave in search '
                            '\n'
                            'of a better life? [y/n]', fill='white')

    y = Button(root, text='Y', command=buttonFunctionY, bg='black', bd=5, font=('Times', 20), activebackground='blue',
               activeforeground='black', fg='black')
    y.place(x=435, y=465)

    n = Button(root, text='N', command=buttonFunctionN, bg='black', bd=5, font=('Times', 20), activebackground='blue',
               activeforeground='black', fg='black')
    n.place(x=485, y=465)

    if option == 'y':
        canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=tkinter.NW, image=image)
        canvas.create_text(485, 375, font=("Times", 25, 'bold'),
                           text='Great, good decision. First should you prepare for the trip by buying supplies? [y/n]',
                           fill='white')

    canvas.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

My main problem is near the end, where I tried to create a conditional based on whether the button is pressed but I have no idea how to do so.

Comment: I guess you could have the command of the buttons be a function which loads the next screen - the conditional could be which function is run?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the reaction on click inside the callback function rather than below the button object initialization. Probably you have `buttonFunctionY` defined. If so then add lines to output 'good choice' text inside the function. Otherwise, define that `buttonFunctionY` function (before it is used in the button but after imports). Surprisingly, sometimes, in Python, you have to define functions before they are actually used by the script.

```
def buttonFunctionY():
        canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=tkinter.NW, image=image)
        canvas.create_text(485, 375, font=("Times", 25, 'bold'),
                           text='Great, good decision. First should you prepare for the trip by buying supplies? [y/n]',
                           fill='white')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but when I tried it, it didn't work? Any editions I should make? Clicking the button currently does nothing

Comment: in the beginning

Comment: are you getting any error? are buttons themselves rendered fine?

Comment: worked for me. (though I used a gif image to avoid PIL installation)

Comment: Yeah I think I placed it in the wrong place, but I'm still unsure if I should do this since there are quite a few options and I'm not sure how to format all of that.